# WPF - creating a trigger to use a resource style

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dialog with buttons - the buttons text and functionality are dynamic and changing according to the user's needs. 
In most cases the button style is the default style, in case the button is an OK button, I would like the button to use a different style.
I've tried to add a trigger that will change the button style according to a Boolean property:
(when IsOKButton=true use the "RedButtonStyle")

```
 <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate >
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOKButton}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource RedButtonStyle}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
```

- the RedButtonStyle is a resource style that can be used in diffrent projects for a diffrent buttons type , so the soultion should be in my project and can't be in the resource style itself.

But when using this trigger I get an exception.
"set property system.windows.controls.control.template threw an exception"

Can anyone help me resolve this problem, or suggest an idea to set the style dynamicly?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put the trigger in the style itself:

```
<Style x:Key="OKButtonStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOKButton}" Value="True">
            //Whatever Property is different in the OKButtonStyle
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOKButton}" Value="False">
            //Set it back to default
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then just give your button the style OKButtonStyle from the start.

If want to make your OK Button mostly the same as a more general style which you want all your buttons to have you can just base it on the general one like this:

```
<Style x:Key="OKButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource GeneralButtonStyle}">
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I'm not sure I will be able to do it this way since the Style I'm using is a resource style for the entire system . In my View  I'm using it as an OK button style but It isn't always the case for other views.

Comment: I've edit my original question to make it more clear. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: That's why I added the bit at the end. You can just write a new style based on the red button style which has the datatrigger in it.

Comment: Ok, Now I got you. Thanks, this will resolve my problem.

Comment: Any idea why I cannot use Style.Trigger?  I have it within Application.Resources - looks like the schema does not like it.  Where should it go?